# Unable to rename domain controller: Account already exists

Tags: active-directory, domain, windows-server-2016

I successfully demoted an old domain controller (Windows Server 2016) in a clean manner, cleanly removed the server from the domain, deleted the associated object in 'Computers' on Active Directory Users and Computers, but when I went to rename the new domain controller (Windows Server 2019) to the name of the old domain controller, I get the following error:

```
The account already exists.
```

So I scoured Active Directory Users and Computers, DNS Manager, Active Directory Sites and Services, and even the registry on the domain controller itself. I've restarted the domain controller numerous times. There is no mention of the old domain controller's name, but I still get this error, regardless of whether I run Rename-Computer In Powershell, or NETDOM at the command line:

```
The account already exists.
```

Now, the old domain controller was running Active Directory Certificate Services as well, but I removed all the data entries created by the old CA service from Active Directory Sites and Services.

Is there any place else to look for references to the old domain controller?

Answer (score 4):

I found out what the problem was:

There apparently was an entry in ADSI Edit under:

Configuration -> CN=Sites -> CN=Default-First-Site-Name -> CN=Servers -> CN={Old Domain Controller}.

The thing is, in ADSI Edit, 'Configuration' isn't normally shown by default (at least with the Remote Server Administration Tools), you have to right-click on 'ADSI Edit' in MMC, and in the 'Connection Settings', under 'Connection Point', and under 'Select a well known Naming Context', you select 'Configuration'. You can also type it under the 'Name' field at the top. So it looks like that one entry was what was blocking me from changing the name.

Comment: This should have been shown in AD Sites & Services, too...

Comment: yes, but it should also be fixed by MS, because after you used the gui to rename the DC and the process failed, you are not able to reverse the change and leave you back with a broken system. At least after the reboot, you have to reverse your change, by again rename backup with the gui or use `netdom comutername` (which also fails, but after a reboot all look good again).

Comment: @Thomas - AD Sites & Services does not get configured automatically because there is no (easy) way to configure it automatically. When promoting a new DC you should always assign it to the correct site and when demoting a DC you should always remove it from the site. That said, I can think of no good reason why anyone should reuse an old DC name in the first place.